# When getting data from two tables how can i make it so it doesnt duplicate the same result?

Tags: php, sql

I am attempting to get my head around retrieving data from multiple tables that share the same factor in this case it would be `something`. It's working fine however, whenever it displays the results it duplicates the same row from table `videos` for every comment that it displays, i know this is due to the fact that i have only uploaded 1 video and there is multiple comments but I'm otherwise unsure how to rectify it. Thanks in advance

```php
$query = "select * from videos,comments where videos.something=comments.something ORDER BY comments.id,videos.id DESC"; 

if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {

    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

        $field1name = $row["id"];
        $field2name = $row["videoname"];
        $field3name = $row["username"];
        $field4name = $row["time"];
        $field5name = $row["description"];
        $field5name = $row["description"];

        $views = $row["views"];
        $uservideos = $row["user"];
        $comment = $row["comment"];

        echo '<div class=videos><p>'.$field3name.' '.$field2name.'</p>';
        echo '<p>'.$usa.' '.$comment.'</p></div>';

    }

    $result->free();
}
```

Comment: You're right in that it is because 1 video has many comments. What are you trying to accomplish with this code? Showing all comments for a single video?

Comment: You can use `DISTINCT` or  `GROUP BY` by column.

Comment: no so i am attempting to create a live feed which shows videos uploaded and all the comments within the website, so users can easily see what is going on- thanks

Comment: @Froxz could you please expand a bit more?

Comment: @RyanCharlesworth to avoid duplicates you can `GROUP BY` by column that is duplicated eg. `video_id`: `GROUP BY video_id`, this will fetch `unique` records of the same `video_id` https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp

Comment: @froxz thanks, ill read that now

Comment: @Froxz that somewhat works for the videos now, but the comments arent being displayed correctly, apologies for being a pain in advance.

Comment: What is `$usa`?

Answer (score 0):

The relation is one to many, each video has many comment and because you need all comments you should manage the logic using code not SQL. See sample code with comments

```
//use join and join on common field it should be video id in your case, don't select * because both tables have column id 
$query = "SELECT v.id AS video_id, v.videoname, v.views, v.user, c.username, c.time, c.comment, c.description AS comment_description, v.description AS video_description FROM videos AS v LEFT JOIN comments AS c ON v.something = c.something ORDER BY v.id DESC, c.id DESC"; 

// no videos have many comments so we will build our logic to ignore diplaying video info many times.  
if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {

    $current_video_id = null;
    // I will use this counter to see when I need to close a div
    $need_to_close_div=false;
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

        $field1name = $row["video_id"];
        $field2name = $row["videoname"];
        $field3name = $row["username"];
        $field4name = $row["time"];
        $field5name = $row["video_description"];
        $field5name = $row["comment_description"];

        $views = $row["views"];
        $uservideos = $row["user"];
        $comment = $row["comment"];

        if(is_null($current_video_id) || $current_video_id != $field1name)
        {
            if($need_to_close_div)
            {
                echo '</div>';
                $need_to_close_div = false;
            }
            $current_video_id = $field1name;
            echo '<div class=videos><p>'.$field3name.' '.$field2name.'</p>';
            //I open a div so I need to close it later 
            $need_to_close_div = true;

        }
        // remove the closing div 
        echo '<p>'.$usa.' '.$comment.'</p>';

    }

    //check after while to close div
    if($need_to_close_div)
    {
        echo '</div>';
        $need_to_close_div = false;
    }
    $result->free();
}
```

I hope that the sample code explain the idea, but it is better to separate the view, so create a array of videos and each video have array of comments and then create the view.